# Magnetic fields in curved wires

Tags: special-relativity, magnetic-fields

Why does Ampère's law/Magnetic part of Lorentz force hold for curved wires if magnetic force is caused by relativistic effects and these only happen in inertial reference frames?
The particles would have to experience change in their velocity in order to follow the curves.

Comment: Not sure why you deleted your other post. However your mistake lies in the fact that in my reference frame, it is inertial. The fact that particles in the wire undergo acceleration is irrelevant to MY frame of reference.

Comment: But isn't the particles reference frame which determines magnetic effects? The fact that there is length contraction for the negative charge changes the charge density and hence there is a force in a direction perpendicular to their motion. PD: I deleted the post because it was closed for not being specific enough so I made a new one including more details.

Comment: To quote Edward Purcell's Electricity and magnetism: "The trouble is that an electron moving on a circular path is an accelerated charge, whereas the magnetic fields we have rigorously derived are those of charges moving with constant velocity. We shall therefore abandon our program of derivation at this point and state the remarkable simple fact: these more general fields obey exactly the same law". They take this as an experimental fact and compare this with taking Coulomb's law as an experimental fact. The problem with this is that magnetic fields can no longer be derived from Coulombs'law.